# why I am geting this error: System.Runtime.interopservice.ComException on windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am using Windows Authentication in asp.net every thing is ok in local but when deploying on different system of same domain then its working getting error in this line SearchResult userObject = adSearcher.FindOne();

Error

system.runtime.interopservice.comException

My code is

```
    WindowsIdentity winId = id as WindowsIdentity;
    if (id == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Identity is not a windows identity");
        return;
    }

    string userInQuestion = winId.Name.Split('\\')[1];
    string myDomain = winId.Name.Split('\\')[0];                       
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + myDomain);
    DirectorySearcher adSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

    adSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    adSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=" + userInQuestion + "))";
    SearchResult userObject = adSearcher.FindOne();
    StringBuilder data =new StringBuilder();
```

Error page:
[link text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khmR3.jpg)

Comment: Please add more information. COMException is a very general exception. Add information like which COM cmponent you are using, what is the hresult, what was the exact call to the COM object

Comment: What Midhat was asking for is the stack details at the COMException - as s/he said, it's too darned generic an exception to know where to start.

Comment: hyperlinked error page, check it out

Answer (score 1):

From your error page, it's failing on the directory Bind.  Does the app pool on the new machine have authority to query AD?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim Connection As New ADODB.Connection
     Connection.Open(ConnectionString)
     Dim Insname As String
     Dim postname As String
```